# DISM Restore Source error

Tags: windows-10, dism

Having problems installing RSAT, which led me to running `scf /scannow`, and it reporting `found corrupt files`. So I'm runnning `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` which complained `...source files could not be found ... Use the "Source" option to specify the location...`.

Other posts cite this command to repair after you have downloaded source: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:E:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` I used the media creation tool to download the Win10 ISO. However, after I mount the ISO and take a look at the sources directory, there is NOT any "install.wim" file, nor any other path on the ISO. There is only a 302MB "boot.wim" and a 3GB "install.esd". Ran the command anyway, but it failed with same `source files could not be found` message. What kind of download do I need to make with MCT that has this "install.wim" file, or is there some other way to invoke `DISM /RestoreHealth`?

**Edit**
I later read the ESD is a compressed & encrypted successor to WIM. Other post had a slightly different usage. I tried `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:E:\sources\install.esd:1 /limitaccess` but still received `Error: 0x800f081f source files could not be found`

Wondering... Does repair require the ISO/WIM/ESD to be the same version as my install? Is it giving this error because it is different? MCT has no prompts for which version ISO to download. How do I download an older release if that's what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Never found a way to get an older ISO via MCT. Did find another site with links to Microsoft.com for them http://windowsiso.net. The ISO checksum from that service also matched a post from Microsoft.com. With the ISO version that matched my install, `DISM Restore` and `SFC /ScanNow` were finally successful.

Alas, the problem I was hoping the DISM would fix is still unresolved. If you know how to fix `0x80073701 Referenced assembly could not be found` when attempting to add Feature for the AD PowerShell module, drop me a line. I guess I may need to make a another post...